# Automate DevExpress Spreadsheets/ GridViews with WinAppDriver

Tags: c#, devexpress, ui-automation, winappdriver

I am trying to automate a WinForm application using WinAppDriver (https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver).

This application is using DevExpress. I need to properly handle a Spreadsheet or GridViews Controls from DevExpress. The only possible solution that I found is to interact with Actions and move the mouse to specific location on the screen. But there are 2 problems:

1. Get/Set data to specific Row/Column
2. The application may be running over different Screen Resolutions so the X,Y locations won't match.

Can someone help me with this?

Code to interact with the Spreadsheet:

```
 _driver.Current.FindElementByName("FormContainer").Click();
 var spread = _driver.Current.FindElementByAccessibilityId("spreadsheet");
 Actions ac = new Actions(_driver.Current);
 ac.MoveToElement(spread).MoveByOffset(-600,-220).Click().SendKeys("11").Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem today. If your `spreadsheetcontrol` has an associated `spreadsheetnamebox`, the workaround consists in changing the `namebox` text value.

If you set the `namebox` edit value to `A6` for example (much easier to achieve ;-)), the focus will be set in the `A6` cell in the `spreadheetcontrol`. A simple 
`session.Keyboard.SendKeys` will then allow you to change the cell value.

You can also use the `formulabarcontrol` in order to read/write the cell content. 
But without these two controls, I didn't find any other reliable solution to automate the `spreadsheetcontrol` (note that the same difficulty occurs with Microsoft Excel test automation...).